# Achievement Ol' Buddy Ol' Pal not unlocked

Tags: achievements, fallout-new-vegas

I still haven't gotten the `Ol' Buddy Ol' Pal` achievement unlocked. I read about the bug on the [fallout wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ol%27_Buddy_Ol%27_Pal) but to the best of my knowledge, I have had achievements enabled all the time. Will I ever be able to get that achievement now?

Comment: I know it's been a long time but I wanted to put something straight. I was able to get the acheivement even though I didn't get on my first recruitment. I got it with Raul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for that character.  However, you can make a new game and try it again with a different character.  It doesn't take too long before you can recruit your first companion.